# Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS

Tags: sql, sql-server

Este es mi query ...

```
DECLARE @fecha0 datetime
SET @fecha0 = (select top 1* 
    FROM events
    WHERE plate like '%D7Z716%' AND
        CONVERT(varchar, received, 103) = CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 103) AND ADDRESS LIKE '%W BAYER%')

IF EXISTS(SELECT ISNULL(MIN(received),'') AS fecha 
    FROM events 
    WHERE plate LIKE '%D7Z716%'
        AND CONVERT(varchar,received,103)=CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 103) AND ADDRESS LIKE '%W BAYER%')
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP(1) received 
    FROM events 
    WHERE received > @fecha0
END
```

El error que me sale.

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not
>   introduced with EXISTS.

Comment: This is SO en español. Please translate your question...

Comment: Espero estes bien Kevin, este sitio es Stack OverFlow en Español, te invito a que traduzcas tu pregunta. Saludos.

Comment: oh sorry.......

Answer (score 2):

Tu inconveniente se encuentra en el primer subselect, al momento de cargar la variable **@fecha0** no devuelve una columna en específico.

```
DECLARE @fecha0 datetime
SET @fecha0 = (SELECT TOP(1) * -- Aquí debes especificar la columna, no usar "*"
    FROM events
    WHERE plate like '%D7Z716%' AND
        CONVERT(varchar, received, 103) = CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 103) 
        AND ADDRESS LIKE '%W BAYER%')

IF EXISTS(
    SELECT ISNULL(MIN(received),'')
    FROM events
    WHERE plate LIKE '%D7Z716%'
        AND CONVERT(varchar,received,103) = CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 103) 
        AND ADDRESS LIKE '%W BAYER%'
)
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP(1) received 
    FROM events 
    WHERE received > @fecha0
END
```

Espero mi respuesta te haya ayudado.